# NameError: name 'addTimeInterval' not defined

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I'm trying to run a code on Hull-White one factor model and at this point in time:

```
today           = datetime.date(2014,10,24)

spot_rate       =   0.02
fardate         = today + addTimeInterval(10.0, 'y')
```

I get this error message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-e46904f6da74> in <module>()
     59 
     60 spot_rate       =   0.02
---> 61 fardate         = today + addTimeInterval(10.0, 'y')
     62 year_fraction   = YearFractionFactory.create_istance(day_count_basis.basis_lin_act_365)
     63 df              = 1.0 / ((1.0 + spot_rate / 365.0) **(year_fraction(today, fardate) * 365.0))

NameError: name 'addTimeInterval' is not defined
```

I dont'know how to fix it :( any answer or hint is appreciate. Thank you all, really..

Stef

edit: I think I found the problem. I'm using and modifying a code that our professor provided to us (we attended a workshop in which he used this code and he told us to use it if we need it). I think he imported a module called calendar.pyc which has this kind of functions. Of course I don't have it in my Python library..Thank you all! I think I'm going to create new functions for addTimeInterval and YearFraction using the module datetime.

Comment: Well, did you define or otherwise import that function?

Comment: You're right..I didn't! I'm new in Python and I have to use it in order to get results for my practical part of the thesis..I'm trying to learn as fast as I can! 
Can I use the code:
def addTimeInterval(self) ? 

Sorry if I bother you..I'm working on codes and problems day and night and I'm not used to deal with python language :(

Comment: Yes, you must `def` it (not sure if you need the self parameter) and return some `datetime` object in order for your addition operation to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to share a full-working example. In your code, you had at least to import the datetime function.

Your code tells you that there is a NameError:

```
NameError: name 'addTimeInterval' is not defined
```

The object `addTimeInterval` which seems not to be a function of the datetime package is unknown.

Maybe timedelta is what you are looking for:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
newtime = date(2014,10,24) + timedelta(days=365.25*10)
```

However, this is hard to say because your question is not very concrete. Consider rephrasing your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I imported datetime at the beginning. However in my code I have a previous 'addTimeInterval' but I only get the error message on the second one

Comment: Could you post your code (remember to shorten your code to the minimum example)? Then I can look over it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I managed the problem, it was a problem with one of the modules not imported properly! Thank you!